# VIM source file on OS condition using interpolation in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I'd like to `source` files based on my OS platform in my .vimrc configuration file. I'd like to do something like this:

`source .vimrc/{uname -S}.vim`

I'm doing this because I'd like to source files based on operating system. I know my syntax is wrong, but I think you get the idea. How would I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Ah. I _get_ it. You want to use `:source` from _within_ vim. Duh. Silly me

Comment: @sehe yes, sorry. I made my question more clear.

Comment: Yes, my original question wasn't phrased specifically. I added more specifics. Sorry.

Comment: I'm basically wanting to to create a vim config file that includes my typical settings and then have platform specific config settings for the multiple platforms I use VIM on. It's becoming a nightmare between osx, bsd and linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think OP wants to source the vim file in vim (e.g. vimrc) not in shell. so you could try to add this line in your vimrc:

```
execute 'source path/to/'. substitute(system('uname -s'), "\n", "", "") . '.vim'
```

Comment: I think your close @Kent. but the suffix '.vim' isn't showing. However, 'Darwin' does get resolved.

Comment: @EhevuTov sorry I didn't test that line. and I found out there is an annoying new line at the end, that's why the `.vim` was not there. pls test the updated answer

Answer (score 3):

This what I have in my `vimrc`:

```
let os=substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')

if os == 'Darwin'
    " settings for Mac OS X

elseif os == 'Linux'
    " settings for Linux

endif
```

-- EDIT --

For what it's worth, I've written that snippet a "long" time ago and I can't remember *why* I added `Mac`. I initially thought that, maybe, I had found out that `uname` reported `Mac` in some context for some reason, but no, it appears to be `Darwin` everywhere. So I've removed `Mac` for that snippet to make more sense and will do the same to my `vimrc`.